# Two different implementations declared in same .m with duplicate declaration of (different!) method

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm pretty new to Xcode, so please bear with me.

I have a class in a static library that implements two classes in the same file. These two classes are different and both randomly share a method of the same name and type. Xcode is saying this is a "duplicate declaration of method" error even though they are clearly in two separate classes. Here is a simplification of what the file looks like:

```
@implementation ImageInfo 

- (NSString *) description {
    //method stuff
    return @"something_meaningful";
}

@end

// later on in the (same .m) file...

@implementation Image

- (NSString *) description {
    //some more method stuff
    return @"something_equally_meaningful";
}

@end
```

Again, the error I am getting is: `Duplicate declaration of method 'description'` at both of these functions.

Please let me know if there's any other information I can supply. As I said, I'm new to Xcode/Objective-C so I'm hoping it's just something silly! Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you're declaring two classes in the same .m?

Comment: Nope. I was hoping to get around this without splitting them up. The code is generated from the Thrift framework.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I pasted your code into mine, added @interface sections, and all was just fine. Conclusion: something else is going on here that you're not telling us. My guess is that these classes _each_ have _another_ `description` (i.e. the problem is not that the two classes conflict but that each class conflicts internally).

Comment: Yea, I realized that @matt and removed my comment.  Muh bad :)

Comment: It looks like you're problem is resolved. Can you accept one of the answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not telling you that `Image` and `ImageInfo` conflict. It is telling you that `Image` has two `description` implementations and `ImageInfo` has two `description` implementations.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That was silly.

Comment: Yes, the "in one file" business is a total red herring. I suspect that if you don't see all the `description` implementations it has to do with the "static library" thing.